# Is the learning of JFrame relavant to android game development

Tags: java, android

I am having a tough time learning JFrame. So I thought that can I skip JFrame or will it effect my ultimate goal of learning android game development?

Comment: Learning anything about games which is not android related will help you of course. You have to learn programming and concepts of game development its not about one particular language or platform. At first at least.

Answer (score 0):

JFrame, is a frame which allows output. Output is the easiest part of any game development. The hardest part is rendering to an Image object, based off a set of 'world' objects that have to be defined by the game logic. A JFrame is just a simple way of outputting your players view into the world. The most crucial part to any game, be it android, iPhone, Xbox, playstation, or PC, is what happens in the background.

for 3D games you need to learn a lot of math - trig, matrices, maybe a little calculus even -, for 2D its a lot simpler, however you still need to know some math. You may wish to implement some simple physics, in which case youll need a comprehensive knowledge of mechanics, and how objects interact with each other. youll then need to build something that can manage these objects and implements all the functionality above.

Having done the above, you now need to render these world objects to an area of memory, so that they can be read by the output device, be it a JFrame, or smartphone screen and shown to the user.

To conclude, I would not get yourself hung up on smartphone development, using swing or awt can be a lot simpler than developing on a smartphone, and the back end of your program, which will most likely account for over 90% of your code, can, in most cases, just be swapped out for the smartphone code and just change the front end.

Hope this helps